# Two-factor Authentication for IBM Domino XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I am a new Domino XPages developer. Does anyone know of a Two Factor Authentication solution for Xpages.

Answer (score 2):

You don't authenticate with an application on Domino. (That's true whether it's built with XPages or not.) You authenticate with the server.  IBM does not support two factor authentication for Domino, but a simple google of "[lotus domino two factor authentication](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lotus%20domino%20two%20factor%20authentication)" will bring up results that include a few vendors of 3rd party solutions that work with Domino. You will, however, have to approach this as a systems admin issue, not a development problem, so if you have any follow-ups they will belong on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://www.duosecurity.com/product/applications/api which you could use after user successfully authenticates against Domino server.